# Breakpoint not getting hit in Visual Studio Kernel driver debugger

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging, wdk

After putting a lot of effort I successfully fixed Visual Studio crash trying to start debugging the remote kernel app by installing Windows 10.0.10586 on both Host and Remote computers. Now the driver gets installed and Visual Studio starts its debugger in Kernel mode and I can see Kernel as the current attached process. The problem is, the code seems not getting executed at all. I set a breakpoint on return 0 and nothing happens after waiting 5 minutes.

Here's my code:

```
#pragma warning(disable : 4100)
#include <ndis.h>
#include <fwpmk.h>
#include <fwpvi.h>
#include <fwpsk.h>

extern "C" {
    NTSTATUS DriverEntry(
        _In_ struct _DRIVER_OBJECT *DriverObject,
        _In_ PUNICODE_STRING       RegistryPath
    )
    {
        DbgPrint("test code");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Can you help me get it work? I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with Windows 10.0.10586 WDK. Remote computer is actually a VM.

Comment: DbgPrint only sends message to kernel debugger.  See for details: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/iliast/2006/12/11/windbg-tutorials/

Comment: @iz25: Isn't "Visual Studio Kernel Debugger" a kernel debugger? At least its name indicates that.